# XUL accessing resources and application structure

Tags: resources, xul, structure

So I'm new to XUL.

As a language it seems easy enough and I'm already pretty handy at javascript, but the thing I can't wrap my mind around is the way you access resources from manifest files or from xul files. So I did the 'Getting started with XULRunner' tutorial... https://developer.mozilla.org/en/getting_started_with_xulrunner
and I'm more confused than ever... so I'm hoping someone can set me straight.

Here is why... (you may want to open the tutorial for this).

The manifest file, the prefs.js and the xul file all refer to a package called 'myapp', that if everything I've read thus far on MDN can be trusted means that inside the chrome directory there must be either a jar file or directory called myapp, but there is neither. The root directory of the whole app is called myapp, but I called mine something completely different and it still worked.

When I placed the content folder, inside another folder called 'foo', and changed all references to 'myapp' to 'foo', thus I thought creating a 'foo' package, a popup informed me that it couldn't find 'chrome://foo/content/main.xul', though that's exactly where it was.

Also in the xul file it links to a stylesheet inside 'chrome://global/skin/' which doesn't exist. Yet something is overriding any inline styling I try to do to the button. And when I create a css file and point the url to it, the program doesn't even run.

Can someone please explain what strange magic is going on here... I'm very confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you register a `content` folder in a `chrome.manifest` you must use the following format:

```
content packagename uri/to/files/ [flags]
```

The `uri/to/files/` may be absolute or relative to the location of the manifest. That is, it doesn't matter what the name of the containing folder is relative to your package name; the point is to tell chrome how to resolve URIs of the following form:

```
chrome://packagename/content/...
```

The `packagename` simply creates a mapping to the location of the files on disk (wherever that may be).

Comment: So are you saying that the chrome.manifest is where you name the package and therefore define the chrome:// url. And therefore the chrome:// url doesn't necessarily have to represent an exact directory structure with the chrome directory as its root?

Comment: @cybermotron: Yes, that's exactly what he is saying. In fact, a `chrome/` directory is convention, it doesn't really have to be there. You could have a `foobar/` directory in your extension's root and map it to `chrome://packagename/content/` with `content packagename foobar/`. Chrome namespaces define a logical structure, they don't need a representation on disk in that form.

Answer (score 1):

The `chrome` protocol defines a logical package structure, it simply maps one URL to another. The structure on disk might be entirely different and the files might not even be located on disk. When the protocol handler encounters an address like `chrome://foo/content/main.xul` it checks: "Do we have a manifest entry somewhere that defines the content mapping for package foo?" And if it then finds `content foobar file:///something/` - it doesn't care whether that URL refers to a file, it simply resolves `main.xul` relatively to `file:///something/` which results in `file:///something/main.xul`. So `file:///something/browser.xul` will be the URL from which the data will be read in the end - but you could also map a chrome package to another chrome URL, a jar URL or something else (theoretically you could even use http but that is forbidden for security reasons).

If you look into the Firefox/XULRunner directory you will see another `chrome.manifest` there (in Firefox 4/5 it is located inside `omni.jar` file). That's where the mappings for `global` package are defined for example.

Comment: Thanks this has really saved me some hair folicals.